# Problems with appending to a list in recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

My code:

```
matrix = []
dynamicmatrix = []
answers = []

...some other code...

def search(chartofind, row):
    global dynamicmatrix

    print("SEARCHING", chartofind, row)

    if row == numberofrows:
        toadd = dynamicmatrix.copy()
        answers.append(toadd)
        return


    for col in range(0, numberofrows):
        if canPlace(chartofind, row, col) == False and matrix[row][col] != chartofind:
            continue
        if matrix[row][col] == chartofind:
            search(chartofind, row+1)
        else:
            dynamicmatrix[row][col] = chartofind
            search(chartofind, row+1)
            dynamicmatrix[row][col] = matrix[row][col]

search("A", 0)        
for i in answers:
    print(i)
```

The problem is that when I print **toadd** in the recursion, it is fine. However, after looping through the list it was appended to; **answers**, it shows a different value than it showed when I appended it to the list. The value inside the recursion was correct but after the recursion the whole list **answers** is ruined. What might be causing this? It is driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would using `global dynamicmatrix` + `global answers` change your problem? Your code is incomplete - you are never calling search... `numberofrows` is used but not defined, etc.

Comment: I forgot to copy the search call there. That will be fixed. The fix you suggested didn't unfortunately work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `.copy()` takes a shallow copy of `dynamicmatrix`, which means that the nested lists in the matrix are referenced in the copy as well, and any subsequent change you make to those nested lists will affect the copy as well.

For instance, the following assignment will affect what you already appended to `answer`:

```
dynamicmatrix[row][col] = chartofind
```

Solution:

Use `deepcopy`:

```
import copy
toadd = copy.deepcopy(dynamicmatrix)
```

Or use list comprehension to make the deeper copy explicitly:

```
toadd = [row[:] for row in dynamicmatrix]
```